# How to create a single image style for both landscape and portrait images?

Tags: 7, media

In a Drupal 7 environment, I want to apply a style to all images within a view. I want every image to be 180px wide & 128px high -OR- 128px wide and 180px high depending on the orientation of the original image.

Can this be done with an image style or do you know any module that would help in achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ImageCache Actions](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions)

> Aspect Switcher new 2009-08 - lets you perform different actions or
>   use different dimensions based on whether the image is 'landscape' or
>   'portrait'

Comment: Linking to the official project page for modules is preferred, if possible.

Comment: If you end up doing this, make sure you read issues about ImageMagick compatability.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One needs to create three image styles, one for landscape, one for portrait and one that is doing the switching action. But it works like a charm.